# Message not received by mqtt client

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I'm trying to send a message to a device using mqtt.
The sender can publish a message. It is received by the queue which I made sub to the topic. The receiver is subscribed to the topic. Yet it receives no message.

```
class MQTTSub:
    class MQTTClient:
        def __init__(self, host: str):
           self.host = host
           self.client = mqtt.Client()
        
        def connect(self):
           self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
           self.client.on_message = self.on_message
           self.client.on_subscribe = self.on_subscribe
           self.client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect
           self.client.on_unsubscribe = self.on_unsubscribe
           self.client.on_log = self.on_log
           #bind_address in case of multiple interfaces
           self.client.connect(self.host, 1883, 60)
           self.client.loop_forever()
       
            
       def on_log(self, client, userdata, level, buf):
           logging.debug(f"log| client: {client}, userdata: {userdata}, level: {level}, buf: {buf}")
    
       def on_connect(self, client: mqtt.Client, userdata, flags: dict, rc: int):
           logging.debug(f"connection| client: {client}, userdata: {userdata}, flags: {flags}, rc: {rc}")
           status = self.client.subscribe(topic="/warehouse", qos=2)
           logging.debug(f"status: {status}")
    
       def on_message(self, client: mqtt.Client, userdata, message):
           logging.debug(f"message| client: {client}, userdata: {userdata}, message: {message.payload}")
     
       def on_subscribe(self, client: mqtt.Client, userdata, mid: int, granted_qos: int):
           logging.debug(f"subscription| client: {client}, userdata: {userdata}, mid: {mid}, granted_qos: {granted_qos}")
        
       def on_disconnect(self, client: mqtt.Client, userdata, rc: int):
           logging.debug(f"disconnection| client: {client}, userdata: {userdata}, rc: {rc}")
    
       def on_unsubscribe(self, client: mqtt.Client, userdata, rc:int):
           logging.debug(f"unsubscription| {client}, userdata: {userdata}, rc: {rc}")
    
   @staticmethod
   def subscribe_all():
      with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "warehouses.json")) as warehouses_file:
        warehouses = json.load(warehouses_file)
        for warehouse in warehouses:
            logging.debug(f"warehouse: {warehouse}")
            client = MQTTSub.MQTTClient(warehouse['host'])
            threading.Thread(target=client.connect).start()
```

My logs

```
DEBUG:root:log| client: <paho.mqtt.client.Client object at 0x7f2f26b28050>, userdata: None,
level: 16, buf: Sending CONNECT (u0, p0, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b''
DEBUG:root:log| client: <paho.mqtt.client.Client object at 0x7f2f26b28050>, userdata: None, level: 16, buf: Received CONNACK (0, 0)
DEBUG:root:connection| client: <paho.mqtt.client.Client object at 0x7f2f26b28050>, userdata: None, flags: {'session present': 0}, rc: 0
DEBUG:root:log| client: <paho.mqtt.client.Client object at 0x7f2f26b28050>, userdata: None, level: 16, buf: Sending SUBSCRIBE (d0, m1) [(b'/warehouse', 2)]
DEBUG:root:status: (0, 1)
DEBUG:root:log| client: <paho.mqtt.client.Client object at 0x7f2f26b28050>, userdata: None, level: 16, buf: Received SUBACK
DEBUG:root:subscription| client: <paho.mqtt.client.Client object at 0x7f2f26b28050>, userdata: None, mid: 1, granted_qos: (2,)
```

You can see here that the client is subscribed.
I tried from the same container (docker) with subscribe.callback it works.
I am out of idea to troubleshoot my issue here.

Does someone have a clue ?

Comment: There are some structural errors in the above code: is the `subscribe_all` method supposed to be a static method on the class? If so, it is mis-indented.

Comment: Might be an issue when I pasted it but it's well indented. I'll correct that

Comment: Your code looks like it should work (there are issues; e.g. using QOS2 without setting a clientID or `clean_session = false` is of limited value). How have you confirmed that the broker is getting the messages? Are you able to provide broker logs? (my guess would be that you have an [extra `/`](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices/#never-use-a-leading-forward-slash) - i.e. should use `topic="warehouse"`).

Comment: The broker subscribed itself to the topic, I have the seen the message. I tried with or without the extra slash. Doesn't make a diffrence nor should it if I understood correctly

Comment: Please use a tool like [mosquitto_sub](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html)/[mqttx](https://mqttx.app/) to subscribe to the topic and confirm you receive messages. We need to confirm if the issue is in your code or elsewhere (and the extra `/` is important - see the link in my comment). Please also note that `self.client.loop_forever()` will block forever so using this when you have multiple connections might be an issue (but as your [code is incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I cannot say).

Comment: I subscribed to the topic and can confirm I receive the message. I even managed to receive a message coming from this topic with my container hosting my MQTTClient. As for loop_forever I am using threads so it would only block the thread used right ?

Comment: "only block the thread" correct (sorry I missed the last line of your code); I'm assuming you have a blocking call elsewhere to prevent the app from terminating?. Can you please add details of the test you did to your question (it removes some potential causes but having the detail is important). I have tested your code and, after fixing the indentation (and adding code to call the function/wait forever), it works fine for me (with mosquitto) so please provide more detail (and ideally make the code a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: Well I forgot to wait for the end of my threads on my master thread. I added it but the result is the same. As for the tests, on the broker I did a mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t /warehouse. I also did subscribe.callback from the paho mqtt api in a python shell from the container hosting MQTTSub and both of these work.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the broker logs next. As your code works for me the issue is likely to be something specific to your setup or the way you are running your test (I used `mosquitto_pub` to send the test message to tour code).